# I'm unable to update DB from web console

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

Hi there!

I'm a big fan of Firebase but issues like these just might kill my app before even getting launched!
While I'm a paid customer and ready to pay $25-$100 a month to have a flawless running system, I'm not sure what to do in circumstances likes these. Don't know if there is an issue from my end or if I have written some bad code but I can't work or test my app right now since I get an error "Unable to save field" while trying to change Firestore values from console.

I spent hours yesterday night thinking there is an issue from my end. But Firestore was buggy since last night. Result: my app is constantly crashing and my time is very valuable. Please, someone, suggest something!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not Firebase Support. This is Stack Overflow, a site for programming questions.

Comment: You should direct this question to the [Firebase Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk)

Comment: If your time is valuable, you shouldn't rely on Firestore since it is currently in Beta release. It still has some bugs and you might want to help the team solve it by filing a [bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/)...  You said you're a fan of Firebase, so you might want to use the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database) in the mean time.